# Hypothesis Testing Using Critical Values

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, independence

If my data $X_i\sim N(\mu,σ^2)$ is iid with a sample $n=35$

If my 99% confidence interval is $[.56,1.86]$ where $P(t>2.7238)=.005$ for a $t(34)$ random variable $t$

How would I derive $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ and test

$H_0:\mu=1.5$ against $H_1:\mu\neq1.5$ at the 1% level? I am really stuck, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your confidence is of the form $\bar x \pm t^\ast SE$, where $t^\ast = 2.7238$ and $SE = \sqrt{S^2/n}$. This should allow you to find $\bar x$ and $S^2$, and you can take it form there.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I got sample average=1.21 and the sample standard deviation=1.411. Did I do it right? I appreciate your help!

Comment: With $n=35,$ statistics $\bar X = 1.21$ and $S = 1.411$ give the 99% CI $(0.559, 1.861)$. Also, $\mu_0 = 1.5$ is contained in the CI, so $H_0$ is not rejected.